# Default formatting for manually entered enumerate tags

Tags: formatting, enumitem, bold

How can I bold the item numbers in enumerate when I am manually entering them? Here's a MWE and its output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[align=right,label=\bfseries]
\item[25-1] Compute $1 + 1$
\item[25-8] Compute $1 \times 1$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like for it to display **25-1** and **25-8**.

Comment: `\newcommand*\makeboldlabel[1]{\textbf{#1}}` and then `[align=right,before=\let\makelabel\makeboldlabel]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite simple:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[align=right, font=\bfseries]
\item[25-1] Compute $1 + 1$
\item[25-8] Compute $1 \times 1$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

B.t.w., note `align=right`   is the default.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\newcommand*\makeboldlabel[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[align=right,before=\let\makelabel\makeboldlabel]
\item[25-1] Compute $1 + 1$
\item[25-8] Compute $1 \times 1$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```